# Jackson-databind deserializes JSON with missing property as "null" instead of default value

Tags: java, jackson-databind, jackson-annotations

When deserializing a JSON string, missing properties are being set as "null" when they shouldn't be. Below is a POJO class:

```
    @Builder
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    static class MyPojo {
        
        @JsonProperty(value = "OptionalProp", required = false, defaultValue = "")
        @Builder.Default
        @Nullable
        @JsonSetter(value = "", nulls = Nulls.AS_EMPTY)
        private String optionalProp = "";
    
        @JsonProperty(value = "RequiredProp", required = false, defaultValue = "")
        @Builder.Default
        @Nullable
        @JsonSetter(value = "", nulls = Nulls.AS_EMPTY)
        private String requiredProp = "";
    }
```

JSON String to deserialize:

```
{
  "RequiredProp" : "test"
}
```

Here is the deserialization:

```
private final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
private final myPojo = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(inputStream, MyPojo.class);
```

And here is the output:

```
MyPojo(optionalProp=null, requiredProp=test)
```

BUT creating the POJO with builder:

```
        final MyPojo myPojo = MyPojo.builder()
            .requiredProp("test")
            .build();
```

Results in the following POJO:

```
MyPojo(optionalProp=, requiredProp=test)
```

I'm using:

```
Jackson-databind 2.12.x
Jackson-annotation 2.12.x
Jackson-core 2.12.x
```

Is there a minor version change from one of these packages that changes the behavior?

Comment: Can you share an example of the POJO you are trying to read as well as the code that does this?

Comment: Edited with more information @akortex

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from Lombok and not the actual Jackson stuff. Taking a look at the generated source code will give you a clear view of what's happening. Using `Builder.Default` seems to cause the issue as it apparently produces messed up code which removes the initializations you have in place. Removing the annotation restores proper behavior.

This seems to be an issue with Lombok and it is documented [here](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2340). Removing the annotation should result in correct behavior.

Comment: This is very odd. I downgraded Lombok from Lombok-1.16.20 to Lombok-1.16.18 and now the deserialization works as expected ("" instead of null).